# Actionscript ComboBox styling

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have spent many hours trying to work this damn thing out!

so I had finally succeeded in changing and instance off a list skin by referring to this documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f50.html.

```
listInstanceName.setStyle("skin", List_skin_2);
```

But for a combobox, this becomes more complicated. I have tried many combinations and I understand that the combobox also uses the list class to act as its dropdown. some things I tried are:

```
comboboxInstance.dropdown.setStyle("skin", List_skin_2);
comboboxInstance.list.setStyle("skin", List_skin_2);
```

i have even gave the list an instance name inside the combobox eg. combolist

```
comboboxInstance.combolist.setStyle("skin", List_skin_2);
combolist.setStyle("skin", List_skin_2);
```

Nothing is working, can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this with the Components window and the Flash IDE. Go to Window > Components to view if it isn't open, then drag a ComboBox onto the stage. Double click the standard ComboBox to open the symbol. Double click the state of the ComboBox you want to edit first, then change the colors / shape and save your Flash file. Test your movie to see the change you have created. Doing it this way will affect all ComboBox controls you use in the project, so you could move it outside your stage and add other ComboBox controls as needed with code if you want.

Comment: Thanks miahelf, I was aware off this method. but I did not wish to have my other listbox to change that was on stage. I eventually found a way to do what i was trying to achieve but it has been awhile for me too even remember what i did. I will have to look at my code sometime and post it on here in case someone else needs help with this issue.